# So "how do I do this" with no effort shown is on topic now?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21238738/1339987).

The new close reasons do not include "no research effort shown or attempt at solution made", so I just downvoted and left.

Is this by design?

Comment: Is that question a good example? It's not just "how do I do this", it includes code.

Comment: @KeithThompson no...  it doesn't include any attempts to solve the problem just basically a `// how do I do this part???` in some other code.